# Spring boot - consuming SOAP web service over HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, soap, https

I have built a simple SOAP web service client using the Spring boot tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/. It works perfect.

The trouble begins if I want to switch to an HTTPS version of the webservice. I debugged usage of my SSL certificate and key in Python and now I want to start HTTPS connection in the tutorial-based project as well but I am lost.

What is the simplest possible way to add my SSL certificate and key to the Spring `WebServiceTemplate` (`org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate`) so I can start signing my messages? I would like to keep and use the generated Java classes created automatically by Maven from the web service's WSDL, I just want to add SSL support. I already have a keystore ready.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: You can probably get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419791/using-webservicetemplate-with-a-keystore